# Push Notification by gmail web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, gmail-api

In my app i have different user who send message from gmail I want to get replies so , I am trying with gmail push notification

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

So my question here is do I need to create the topic subscription at app level or at user level

Means every user will have there own topic or only the app will have the topics and subscription

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really difficult to debug a verbal description of your code... how about you edit your question and add the relevant sections of your code. Then tell us what you have tried, and the error you are experiencing (eg what you expect and what you saw instead). then we can begin to help you.

Comment: I am using api explorers provided by gmail, so I am asking a suggestion, before i am starting to code is at application level or at user level

Comment: I'm afraid that Stack Overflow doesn't work that way. We won't design your code for you. The way this works is - you have a go at it first yourself. if you get stuck, then you show us what you tried and why it doesn't work and we'll help you debug it and make it work.

Comment: @TarynEast I was not expecting code, Please ready my question if you did not get it, I was asking should "create the topic subscription at app level or at user level"

Comment: You are asking us to design an aspect of your app for you... which is my point. As I mentioned in my comment - generally speaking, we expect you to have a go at writing your code (which includes designing your app) yourself.